# Write a program to get below output

Tags: javascript, recursion, logic

I have been asked to write a program to get output as **60** when function has been invoked like `multipliedResult(3)(4)(5);` in javascript.
How to write a function to get above result? Whether it should be recursive program?

Comment: We won't write your code for you, but I'll guide you in the right direction: a function like this is called a *curried* function, and involves *returning functions from functions*.

Comment: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: java is completely different from javascript

Comment: Is this a Java or Javascript question? I'm sorry to say this but it surprised me when a senior developer is asking a college level programming question like this one.

Comment: JavaScript: `console.log((a => b => c => a * b * c)(3)(4)(5))`

Comment: @user3437460 it surprises me you think titles are representative of anything meaningful 

Answer (score 1):

Just look closely, Function `multipliedResult` returns another function.

So, JavaScript Code will look like:

```js
function multipliedResult(a){
  return function(b) { 
    return function(c) {
      return a*b*c;
    }
  }
}
console.log(multipliedResult(3)(4)(5))
```

Comment: You have an extra closing bracket after your code sample.